# PHP.. How to loop by some selected number?

Tags: php, html

I need a output like this

```
Number 5
Number 4
Number 9
Number 3
Number 8
Number 10
```

And so on (There are more like this)

I used this code

```
<?php 

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10 ; $i++) { 
        if ($i == 5 || $i == 4 || $i == 9) {   //And so on Like this
            echo "$i<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

But the main problem is output is showing the number **serially**.

```
//It shows
Number 3
Number 4
Number 5
Number 8
Number 9
Number 10

//But I need
Number 5
Number 4
Number 9
Number 3
Number 8
Number 10
```

And this takes much time to code. And it not looks so good. Sure there is a easy way out!

I am expecting something like this -

```
//Surely this is not right. It's just an idea.

<?php 

    $x = 5,4,9,3,8,10;

    for ($i = 0; $i = $x; $i++) { 
        echo "$i<br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: And what is the logic in this sequence?

Comment: If you got those numbers in an array you can just iterate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JustOnUnderMillions's answer is corrent - You can even have access to key & value like this

```
$x = array(
    "num1" => 1,
    "num2" => 2,
    ...
    ...
);

foreach($x as $key => $value){
    echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take this

```
 $x = array(5,4,9,3,8,10);

 foreach ($x as $i) { 
    echo "Number $i<br>";
 }
```

but please, learn the basics of PHP if you really want to code in php.

Comment: Thank you... Ya I'm really new in php